# VBA: post a value to another worksheet based on match criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Edit: Ok I think I was making it too complicated. The below code would do what I want it to but I'm getting a method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
Sub Test()

Dim var1 As String
Dim var3 As Variant
Dim var4 As Integer

var1 = Worksheets("wage run").Range("D1")
var3 = Worksheets("with Changes").Range("A1:A138")

var4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(var1, var3, 0)



Select Case Range("b7").HasFormula
Case Is = False
    Sheets("wage run").Select
    Range("B7").Copy
    Sheets("With Changes").Select
    ***Range(Cells(var4, 5)).Select***
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? post an example so that we can help you easily

Comment: Sorry. I want to take cell b7 and have it paste it to the corresponding row on another tab based on the selected value on the "wage run" tab but only if it is a value and not a formula.

Comment: `Worksheet.Index` is a property, not a method, and it returns a `Long`, not a `Range`. I think you probably forgot `.WorksheetFunction` on the marked line.

Comment: Just to mention: I don't see any use of the second `with` block `With Sheets("wage run")`. This `with` is never used in your code!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was able to dwindle my code down a bit. I'm still getting an error though and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another post. Thank you all for your input!

```
Sub tgr()

Dim rngFound As Range
Dim strFirst As String
Dim strID As String

strID = Worksheets("wage run").Range("D1")

Set rngFound = Worksheets("with changes").Columns("A").Find(strID, Worksheets("with changes").Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    strFirst = rngFound.Address
        End If

Select Case Range("b7").HasFormula
Case Is = False
    Sheets("wage run").Select
    Range("B7").Copy
    Sheets("With Changes").Select
    Cells(rngFound.Row, 5).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("wage run").Select
End Select


Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(strID, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)

Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```